# Is it valid to take the address of a string literal, or to iterate over it?

Tags: c, string, literals

It is certainly valid to do this:

```
char src[] = "Allie has a cat.";
char buff[20];
strcpy(buff, src);
printf("%s\n", buff);
```

Or this:

```
printf("Allie has a cat.\n");
```

But, is it valid to shorten the above code to this?

```
char buff[20];
strcpy(buff, "Allie has a cat.");
printf("%s\n", buff);
```

Or to write:

```
printf("%s", "Allie has a cat.");
```

The reason I’m asking is that AFAIK in C string literals are somewhat different animals than character arrays, and while both examples seem to be working ([ideone#1](http://ideone.com/l9DsIz), [ideone#2](http://ideone.com/enMv2S)), I think that when it comes to C I should not do anything I only suppose should be valid or just seems to be working b/c of the number of pitfalls this language has and how easy it is in this language to write a construct that looks innocent but nevertheless is UB.

Comment: All of the examples should work fine. String literals are just `char` arrays in read only memory. BTW, there is no string literal in the first snippet.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Was the code edited? The first snippet does have a string literal `"Allie has a cat."`.  (It's not used other than to initialize `src`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, yes. It is string literal as per C standard ("*sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes*"), but not in the meaning of "read-only char array having an address in a memory", which can be iterated or taken the address of the OP is concerned about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Detail: " String literals are just char arrays in read only memory" --> string literals may or may not be stored in read-only memory.  Attempting to change data of a string literal may "work",  it might not,  it is UB,

Answer (score 5):

That's perfectly valid. String literals are character arrays:

> **6.4.5 String literals**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>      character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character
>      sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>      sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>      type `char`, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>      sequence [...]
> 6. It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>      appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>      undefined.

(Source: ISO 9899:1999 ("C99"))

So something like

```
strcpy(buff, "Allie has a cat.");
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
static char __s0[] = "Allie has a cat.";
strcpy(buff, __s0);
```

(except modifying a string literal has undefined behavior).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though, one nitpick: AFAIK writing `static char __s0[]` is UB, since [identifiers beginning with a double underscore are reserved and declaring them is UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier). So, these two snippets are not effectively equivalent, since one is UB and the other is not :)

Comment: I wouldn't say the two snippets are equivalent. Well, semantically maybe, if no other code is around, but in the first one the `__s0` will go to initialized `.data` section, while in the second the literal will probably sit in the `.text` or `.rodata` section.

Comment: @gaazkam I'm trying to show what the implementation is doing behind the scenes. That's why my code uses an identifier reserved for the implementation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't actually say what the value of a string literal is. It says the sequence is used to initialize a static array, but it doesn't say that the literal refers to that array. I suppose the intent is sufficiently obvious. (This is a language-lawyer nitpick, not an actual complaint.)

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons, string literals are declared as an array of `char` rather than `const char`, but the standard neither guarantees that they can be modified nor that they cannot.  This is because there were already, by 1989, implementations that did it both ways.  In practice, treat them as `const char[]` today and don’t ever try to modify them.

Compilers are allowed to re-use the same memory for multiple character constants, so don’t assume identical strings or substrings will or will not overlap.

Taking the address, iterating over it and reading the contents up to the terminating null are all perfectly safe.

#### Postscript

The words of the standard, which melpomene quoted in her answer, say that modifying a character constant is **undefined behavior**.  Since that inspired a discussion in the comments, here’s what that means.

If you modify a character in a string literal, you forfeit any guarantees the standard gave you about what the program might do.  The compiler has the blessing of ANSI and ISO to do absolutely anything.  So, if you declare `char hello[] = "hello";` and then `array[4] = 'p';`, here are some things that might happen:

- The compiler could give you an error and reject the program.
- `puts("hello");` could print `hellp`.
- `puts("Say hello");` could print `Say hellp`.
- `puts(hello);` could print `hello`.
- `puts(hello);` could print `hellp`.
- Either `hello` or `"hello"` might inconsistently contain either `hello` or `hellp`, depending on what the optimizer does.
- The program could crash at the line `array[4] = 'p';`
- The superintelligent AI compiling your programs might decide human stupidity is endangering the Mission and try to kill you.

There are examples of each of these behaviors, although that last one might be from some movie.

Comment: It's splitting hairs pretty finely to say that the standard does not guarantee that string literals cannot be modified.  It certainly *does* say that any attempt to modify one produces undefined behavior.

Comment: It’s not safe to do, but I mean that you get no guarantee that the character constant is in read-only memory or that no other part of the code could do it to you. In practice, I don’t think anyone’s done it on purpose in decades.

Comment: @Davislor Not safe to do what, sorry?

Comment: Ok, but that's not particularly distinctive.  In that sense, there's pretty much nothing that the standard guarantees you cannot do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: And undefined behavior can do literally anything. A conforming implementation *could* have this code: `char *s = "hello"; s[0] = 'H';` set the string to `"Hello"`. (And tcc does exactly that, though I don't think it's fully conforming.)

Comment: String literals are of type `char[N]`, where `N` is the length + 1 (for the terminating `'\0'` null character). They are implicitly converted to `char*` in most contexts, but not in all. For example, `sizeof "hello"` is 6, not the size of a pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson You’re correct.  I meant that you can write the declaration `char *m = "hello"`, but `char m[] = "hello"` or `char m[6] = hello"` would be more proper.

Comment: `char m[] = "hello";` and `char m[6] = "hello";` are equivalent. `const char *p = "hello";` is also perfectly valid, but it has a different meaning. `const char m[] = "hello";` is also perfectly valid, and has yet another different meaning.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, and as I said above, I recommend declaring string literals as `const char m[] = "hello";`.

Comment: Just curious, why do you recommend that over `const char *m = "hello";`? (`sizeof` could be a reason for that preference.)

Comment: As you say, `sizeof()`, the compiler noticing out-of-bounds array accesses, the fact that you need to write `const char* const` to tell the compiler to prevent reassigning `m`, compactness.  Maybe that will disable certain memory optimizations on some compilers, but I doubt it today.